# How to drop rows based on year on a based dataframe in a function using *args

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to remove rows from a `DataFrame` based on the year of its index, e.g.:

```
def drop(df, col, *args):
    dropedyrs = df.drop(df.index.year[[args]])

drop(df, 'col', 1999, 2002)

IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

However this produced an error. I'd also tried this approach which also produced an error:

```
dropedyrs = df[df.index.year != args]

KeyError: True
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `col` argument appears to be unused, but, any reason you can't do the following?

```
def drop(df, col, args):
    dropedyrs = df.drop(df.index.year[[args]])

drop(df, 'col', [1999, 2002])
```

Comment: Thanks that was a much less complicated approach than mine!